# text classification using svm

Tags: svm, genetic-algorithm, text-classification

i read this article :**A hybrid classification method of k nearest neighbor, Bayesian methods
and genetic algorithm** 
it's proposed to use genetic algorithm in order to improve text classification
i want to replace Genetic algorithm with SVM but i don't know if it works or not
i mean i do not know if the new idea and the result will be better than this article
i read somewhere ***Ga*** is better than ***SVM*** but i dono if it's right or not?

Comment: Genetic algorithms and SVMs are not mutually exclusive. They are usually used for very different tasks, so I don't know why you want to replace a genetic algorithm with an SVM.

Comment: i want to propose a new idea. this algorithm was about Ga ,i wanna change it with SVM and make a new idea. is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SVM and Genetic Algorithms are in fact completely different methods. SVM is basicaly a **classification** tool, while genetic algorithms are **meta optimisation heuristic**. Unfortunately I do not have access to the cited paper, but I can hardly imagine, how putting sVM in the place of GA could work.

> i read somewhere Ga is better than SVM but i dono if it's right or not?

No, it is not true. These methods are **not comparable** as they are completely different tools.